# How to use SVG filters in vue components?

Tags: css, vue.js, svg, vue-component, vuepress

Hi i am new to vue and i have been trying to apply [css filters](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/filter) from svg file in my component but it doesn't seem to work the "traditional way" i.e just use a css selector like

```
 .selector {
    
    filter: url("colorblind-filters.svg#protanopia");
    
    }
```

yes i tried using another paths like ./, / or even the absolute path

[this is the filter i wanna use](https://gitlab.com/skingrapher/colorblind-filters)